# Closed formula for an integer sequence in two variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, recurrence-relations

When we differentiate the expression $f(u^2)$, we easily obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{du} f(u^2) &= 2 u \ f'(u^2) \ ,\\
&\\
\frac{d^2}{du^2} f(u^2) &= 2  \ f'(u^2)  + 4 u^2 \ f''(u^2) \ .
\end{align*}
However, if we keep differentiating it multiple times, we'll have to apply the product rule giving us a complicated expression similar to the following
$$
\frac{d^n}{du^n}f(u^2) = \sum_{\substack{2j-i = n \\ j\geq i}} d(i,j)\ u^i f^{(j)}(u^2) \ .
$$
My objective is to understand $d(i,j)$, and if possible, **write a closed formula for this sequence**. We assume that $d(i, j) = 0$, whenever $j \geq i \geq 0$ is not satisfied, and furthermore we can write the recurrence relation
$$
d(i,j ) = (i + 1) d(i+1, j) + 2d(i-1, j-1) \ .
$$
The examples that I computed seem to indicate that there should be a formula somewhat resembling the binomial coefficients for this sequence, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Here go some terms I computed:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The triangle of coefficients you have is OEIS sequence [A185296](http://oeis.org/A185296) and there is a falling factorial formula which is very close to binomial coefficients as you suspected. A signed version is OEIS sequence [A059343](http://oeis.org/A059343) which is the coefficients of the Hermite 
polynomials $H_n(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is much better than what I expected to get.